# Pearly White Aeon Stone + Spirit Link

Tags: spells, magic-items, pathfinder-2e, healing

[Spirit Link](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=302):

> While the duration persists, you gain no benefit from **regeneration** or **fast healing**.

The [Pearly White Spindle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=407) does not use any of these phrases:

> When you invest this aeon stone, it slowly starts healing your wounds, **restoring** 1 HP every minute.

It seems they should work together, am I right?

Comment: Strictly RAW the spindle will continue to work, healing 1 hp every 10 rounds. Though I think this is an academic discussion as most combats will be over before the spindle actually provides any healing

Comment: @CaptianObvious Spirit Link, though, has a duration of 10 min., so there's some value here. I'm not sure the return on the investment is high enough, but answers should address that.

Comment: In my experience everyone has the Pearly White anyway, especially in PFS. But yes, the question is not about real optimization

Comment: That's interesting, in my 2 full AP's and 2 half AP's (plus a few smaller Adventures), I think we've a total of about 3 Pearly White's. Partially because it's Uncommon, I think, but also it so rarely seems to be worth the Investment slot when Treat Wounds is usually readily available

Comment: While you Treat Wounds on one person, everyone else (including the healer) gets 10 HP back. If you don't have Continual Recovery, and need to TW twice on the same target, it is 70 HP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Sure

The *pearly white spindle aeon stone* doesn't give fast healing or regeneration, so it is unaffected by the limitations of *spirit link*.

While this is interesting, it really won't break anything balance-wise because the healing is so slow. [Fast healing and regeneration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=796) restore Hit Points to the creature each turn (and often much more than just 1 Hit Point), which would be very effective for sharing that healing.

Even just a trained [Treat Wounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57) for 10 minutes will heal about the same amount as what's being restored by this healing 2d8-4d8 on a DC 15 Medicine check.

There's also the problem that this level 1 spell transfers 2 Hit Points each round, far more than the 1 per minute being restored by the stone. With 10 rounds a minute that means every 20 points lost from the spell the caster would only get 1 back, or 200 Hit Points lost over 10 minutes with 10 restored from the stone, not to mention that the transfer rate increases if the spell is heightened to make this combo even less useful.

Comment: It is meant more like a "going back to the city" city situation. The cleric has the Aeon Stone, the Fighter not, both are damaged a bit. Probably still simpler just to hand over the Aeon Stone once the Cleric is at full health.